# Preventing <code> tags within <pre>

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I am writing documentation using `R Markdown`. After "knitting", the resulting markdown source might look like this:

````
The variables `x` and `p` are related as follows:
```r
x <- 1
c(x = x, p = pnorm(x))
```
```out
        x         p 
1.0000000 0.8413447
```
````

... which when converted using pandoc (with syntax highlighting disabled), results in:

```
The variables <code>x</code> and <code>p</code> are related as follows:
<pre class="r"><code>x &lt;- 1
c(x = x, p = pnorm(x))</code></pre>
<pre class="out"><code>        x         p 
1.0000000 0.8413447</code></pre>
```

The problem is that the `<code>` tag is used, unclassed, in both the body text and the pre-formatted sections. In my case, I would like to write a CSS file that styles the code and output chunks (the R code with class `r` and the output with class `out`) with different colors, and also displays in-text code in a different color than other body text.

I can define colors for the `r` and `out` classes; but if I also define a color for the `code` tag (which I think is very helpful for readability of the text), it overrides those colors in the code and output chunks. If the `<code>` tags weren't in the `<pre>` sections (they seem unnecessary), I'd be fine.

Is there a way to get pandoc to omit the `<code>` tags in the pre-formatted sections? (Or alternatively, to add my classes to the `<code>` tags instead of `<pre>`?) I don't want to use syntax highlighting; just the context highlighting I have described.

Answer (score 0):

OK, duh... After further reading on CSS selectors, I can specify that `code` inherits its color for certain classes. So in my `.css` file, I now have:

```
code { color: #400000; }

.r {color: #800000; }
.r code { color: inherit; }

.out { color: #008000; }
.out code { color: inherit; }
```

... and now I can get 3 different font colors for those situations.

Comment: No need for `inherits`. Just define the color on the `code` tag: `.r code { color: #800000; }`. Then you can eliminate the line: `.r {color: #800000; }`. Same goes for your `.out` class.

Comment: Later styles will override the earlier ones. Therefore, as a general rule, define general styles first, then more specific styles later. This is part of the meaning of "cascading" in "Cascading Style Sheets".